# How to only print file contents if there are 10 more lines?

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I want to print the file content if it contains more then 10 lines ,

I have tried this code, but it does not work

```
import java.io.*;
public class FileExampleOne
{
    public static void main(String args[]) //throws IOException
    {
        //open a file textual for reading
        BufferedReader inFile=null;
        try
        {
            FileReader   in = new FileReader("plz.txt");
            inFile = new BufferedReader(in);

            int line = 0;
            for(String x=inFile.readLine(); x!= null ; x=inFile.readLine())
            {
                line++;
                // System.out.println (x);
                //* it must be something here I guess ...

                if(line>=10)
                {
                    String y=inFile.readLine();
                    while(y!= null)
                    {
                        System.out.println( y);
                        y=inFile.readLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }//try
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("file error "+e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("io error "+e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                inFile.close();
                System.out.println("file is now closed");
            }//try
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("error in finally");
            }//catch
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code you're stuck with and highlight where it is going wrong?

Comment: how many characters are considered as a line?

Comment: @user3419748 probably a line lasts until next linefeed

Comment: There is no limit to the characters that can be part of one line. A line is terminated on a "newline" character. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages

Comment: Where is your code? What is happening? What does `wired way` mean exactly? (I know it's meant to be weird, but still doesn't explain anything). A line ends with a new line character.

Comment: it once counted each 5 lines as one !!

Comment: im trying to share the code but I dont know how :\ .. im new here

Comment: @user3419748: copy the code you've written and edit it into your post (press *edit* right under your post). Afterwards, select all the code you just pasted and press the `{}` button in the editing field to give it code markup. Then press *Save changes*.

Comment: i think I shared it ... thnks

Comment: I cleaned it up a little bit. As a sidenote: try to format your code in your IDE (the program you code in, like Eclipse, Netbeans or IntelliJ) first. This will make it look better. Finally to improve your post: can you also add the expected output and the output you are currently getting? This will make it easier to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Im using Textpad right now cause I want to learn how to write the whole code myself ..I dont rather using Eclipse and I dont have its software now ,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path"));
        String line = null;
        int count = 0;
        while ((reader.readLine()) != null && count < 11) {
            count++;
        }
        if (count > 10) {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path"));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(" the file must have at least 10 lines");
        }
        System.out.println("done");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: alright .. I will try it now

Comment: it worked,but I tried to add a print statement to indicate the user that the file must have at least 10 lines(in the else part of the if statement)and I also bugs in the try catch finally part ...

Comment: so what's the problem ? and as you said it is working so accept it

Comment: it syas i have a "try" without " catch" or "finally" and i didnt know how to fix it..

Comment: your  bracket place is wrong i will change the code and post it for you

Comment: alright, I tried to fix the brackets tho .. but you seem to know better

Comment: is there any other problem ??

Comment: can you tell what is the second " reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("plz.txt")); " is used for ... I typed 10 lines in the file but it went to the else part ....

Comment: ohh alright ... it worked as (count >= 10) , nevermind and thanks any way

Comment: glad to hear that , now you should accept this answer

Comment: i did ... what do you mean with "accept" ?!